# How to set up a virtual screen or desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

On Windows, I installed Rainmeter and while searching through the position options for the widgets, it had a tick box next to my default monitor, but below that it said "@0: Virtual Screen". I did some research and some people called it a Virtual Desktop.

Can anybody give me any information on Virtual Desktops/Screens and how to set one up?

Comment: What do you want to know besides what's in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_desktop)? I don't know about the option you're seeing (care to add a screenshot?), but if you need a Virtual Desktop utility you can use [Desktops from MS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can recommend an answer.

There's an excellent free virtual desktop manager called Dexpot that uses an experimental plugin for Rainmeter called Raindexer.

It allows Rainmeter skins to only be on specific virtual desktops.

http://dexpot.de/?lang=en

Perhaps you found the portion of Rainmeter compatible with Dexpot via Raindexer.